# How to use Python unit tests in self-contained program?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to use Python 3.3 with unit tests in small self-contained program, i.e. I don't want to split it up into a command line part and a "functional" part, which can be tested if it is started on itself on the command line.

So I have this little program:

```
import unittest

def stradd(a, b):
   return a + b

class test_hello(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_1(self):
      self.assertEqual(stradd("a", "b"), "ab")

unittest.main()
print(stradd("Hello, ", "world"))
```

Unfortunately, the print() is never reached, since unittest.main() exits the program.  And even if it would not exit, it would print all kinds of output to the screen that I don't want to see in normal operation.

Is there a way to run the tests silently, as long as there is no error?  Of course, they should complain loudly if something doesn't work.

I've seen [Run python unit tests as an option of the program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9831749/1045800), but that doesn't answer my question as well.

Comment: If these are simple tests, maybe [doctest](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) is an easier option?

Comment: Why doesn't the question you linked answer your question?

Comment: Related: [Run Python unittest so that nothing is printed if successful, only AssertionError() if fails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7181134/95735)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to achieve the effect you want with a plain `unittest` module. You just need to write your own simple test runner. Like this:

```py
import unittest

def stradd(a, b):
    return a + b

class test_hello(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(stradd("a", "b"), "ab")


def run_my_tests(test_case):
    case = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test_case)
    result = unittest.TestResult()
    case(result)
    if result.wasSuccessful():
        return True
    else:
        print("Some tests failed!")
        for test, err in result.failures + result.errors:
            print(test)
            print(err)
        return False


if run_my_tests(test_hello):
    # All tests passed, so we can run our programm.
    print(stradd("Hello, ", "world"))
```

`run_my_tests` function will return `True` if all tests pass successfully. But if there is a test failure, it will print all errors/failures to stdout. For example:

```
$ python myscript.py 
Hello, world

$ # And now the test fails...
$ python myscript.py 
Some tests failed!
test_1 (__main__.test_hello)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 8, in test_1
    self.assertEqual(stradd("a", "c"), "ab")
AssertionError: 'ac' != 'ab'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use python's [nosetests](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/). Then you can write the code exactly the way you want to - with *nothing* except `test_` functions added to the program and run tests via

```
$ nosetests filename.py
```

or

```
$ py.test filename.py
```

Also yeah no need of classes then:

```
def test():
    assert stradd("a", "b") == "ab"
```

Though it doesn't answer you "run silently" part. For me this + command line history works fine. For tiny programs ofc, basically snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Other test frameworks won't help here because it's not test framework which is an issue here. Having said that `py.test` is the best one out there :).

The problem is `unittest.main()` function is designed specifically to run tests in a standard way and does not offer a way to customize this process in any way. This leaves us with two options

- Use `subprocess` for running tests in separate process using `unittest.main()`, check the
  output and continue with running our program if all tests passed
- Leave high level `unittest.main()` alone and use other facilities
  provided by unittest module

I'll write about both of these options as soon as I find some more free time.